# How to call list of variables from a resource file into Robot test?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have 1000 URL names to send to robot test. So that I have planned to assign each URL to a variable called ${ URL1}, ${URL2}... etc. When I use this inside "test.robot" its working as expected.
  But When I call these variables from resource file I am getting "resources.txt' is empty" error as shown in below logs.

```
[ WARN ] Imported resource file 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\IMPORTANT - Robot Fram
work - Final Project Data\URL\resources.txt' is empty.
==============================================================================
Url based apps test suite
==============================================================================
testcase1                                                             | FAIL |
Variable '${URL1}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
testcase2                                                             | FAIL |
Variable '${URL2}' not found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Url based apps test suite                                             | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 0 passed, 2 failed
2 tests total, 0 passed, 2 failed
==============================================================================
```

resources.txt contents:

```
${URL1}     http://www.4shared.com/
${URL2}     http://depositfiles.com/
${URL3}     https://www.gmail.com/
```

test.robot settings content:

```
*** Settings ***

Library         Selenium2Library
Library         SSHLibrary
Suite Teardown  Close All Browsers
Resource        resources.txt
```

Please help to me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your resources.txt should start with the "variables" header:

```
*** Variables ***
${URL1}     http://www.4shared.com/
${URL2}     http://depositfiles.com/
${URL3}     https://www.gmail.com/
```

See [Resource file structure](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-file-structure) in the User Guide: "The higher-level structure of resource files is the same as that of test case files otherwise".